# How to remove unwanted padding between ScrollView/List and other views in a VStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am creating a bottom panel to use within my app. It is not a tab bar so a tab bar wont work, think like the bottom panel in the Voice Memos app. When I try to put this footer that resembles a RoundedRectangle in a VStack with a ScrollView or List it adds padding between the RoundedRectangle and the ScrollView.

[image]

You can see the unwanted padding by addings background(Color.red) to the VStack. Code is here:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Group {
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                }
                
                Group {
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                }
            }
            
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .frame(height: 100)
            }
        }
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

What is the best way to get rid of this? Or, I suppose, what is the best way to add an element like a RoundedRectangle to the bottom of the screen? The ScrollView takes up maximal space so it pushes the RoundedRectangle to the bottom, but can't seem to remove the paddings. I've tried fixing this by adding an offset to the roundedRectangle, but then there's missing space on the bottom. The following preview just adds `.offset(y: -8) to the RoundedRectangle.

[image]

I've then fixed this by ZStack-ing another RoundedRectangle to that to fill the bottom correctly, but it all seems convoluted and hacky. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `VStack(spacing: 0)`

Comment: As said by @jnpdx, some views have a default spacing so if you write `VStack` or `VStack()` you'll get a 10pt or so default spacing. Feel free to add `(spacing: 0)` to any `VStack` or `HStack` where you don't want it.

Comment: Also, do you have something else in your `ZStack`?

Answer (score 0):

IMO you don't need `VStack`: let `List` be your top element, and use `.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom)` modifier on it to display your rounded rectangle:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            // same as before
        } // end of List
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .frame(height: 100)
        }
```

This, btw, will also work if your list is short.